# Nonparametric estimation of the logarithm of a density

Tags: nonparametric, kernel-smoothing, logarithm, nonparametric-density

I was wondering whether there is an equivalent to [Kernel Density Estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) to estimate nonparametrically the *logarithm* of a density. Or if there is any nonparametric method for that. (Taking the logarithm of the kernel density estimate seems suboptimal.)

Could you point towards references dealing with this?

**EDIT.** With suboptimal I mean that $\log \hat f_h(x)$ has some *extra bias* with respect to the bias of $\hat f_h(x)$, although it is still asymptotically unbiased. By a Taylor expansion,
$$
\log \hat f_h(x) = \log(f(x) + \hat f_h(x) - f(x)) \approx \log f(x) + \frac{\hat f_h(x) - f(x)}{f(x)} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{(\hat f_h(x) - f(x))^2}{f(x)^2}.
$$
Then, taking the expectation and pluging-in the bias and MSE expressions for $\hat f_h(x)$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb{E}[\log \hat f_h(x)] &\approx& \log f(x) + \frac{\mu_2(K)f''(x)}{2f(x)} h^2  - \frac{1}{2f(x)^2} \Big(\frac{1}{4}\mu_2(K)^2f''(x)^2h^4 + \frac{R(K)f(x)}{nh}\Big)\\
& = &\log f(x) + O(h^2 + (nh)^{-1})
\end{eqnarray*}
which is larger than the bias of $\hat f_h(x)$, $\mathbb{E}[\hat f_h(x)] = f(x) +O(h^2)$.

Comment: "*Taking the logarithm of the kernel density estimate seems suboptimal*" -- what are you trying to optimize, exactly?

Comment: Hi @Glen_b, thanks for your comment! I guess the Mean Integrated Squared Error, or a similar error measure in the log scale that makes more sense. My first concern when I thought about ``suboptimal'' was about the bias as it was larger than the KDE's. I edited the question in that direction.

Comment: You could perhaps attempt to correct for the bias.